# jQuery UI resizable getting detached

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Flow:

1. My code adds a div with resizable and sortable features on button click.
2. And I enter the text in text field and I'll add that text to that particular div on
    click.

Facing problems:

- Everthing goes good, but resizable is not working after text insertion. I dont know why. I got the solution also, like before appending text i'm destroying the resizable feature to that particular div and attaching after append is over, I think this is not proper solution. Can any one tell why it is happening like that.

Comment: show us some code or a jsfiddle

Comment: You sure you dont add event listeners before adding elements on DOM?